# Mobile service Android and request.parameters

Tags: android, azure, parameters, azure-mobile-services

can someone tell me please is there a way to pass custom parameters on getting table (or insert, update...) from azure mobile services. My scripts sometimes are using request.parameters but I didn't find any example of adding them in Android SDK.

Is there a way?

Comment: On which way FusionCharts are connected to my problem? I'm asking about connecting Azure Mobile Services and Android app so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the [insert | update | delete] methods there is an overload which allow you to pass those parameters - the overload with a `List<Pair<String, String>>` argument. This is how you'd pass a few extra parameters in an insert call:

```
MobileServiceTable<TodoItem> table = mClient.getTable(TodoItem.class);
List<Pair<String, String>> queryParams = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
queryParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("option", "value"));
table.insert(todoItem, queryParams, new TableOperationCallback<TodoItem>() {
    public void onCompleted(TodoItem inserted, Exception error, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
        // Your logic here
    }
});
```

For delete / update, the code is similar.

For query operations, you can pass the parameters via the `parameter` method:

```
MobileServiceTable<TodoItem> table = mClient.getTable(TodoItem.class);
table
    .where().field("complete").eq(val(false))
    .parameter("option", "value")
    .parameter("otherOption", "otherValue")
    .execute(new TableQueryCallback<TodoItem>() {

    public void onCompleted(List<TodoItem> results, int count, Exception error, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
        // Your logic here
    }
});
```